# Why is the standard deviation mismatched in barplot when I am using plotly and crosstalk

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, crosstalk

I want to produce barplot using `plotly` and `crosstalk`, but I found that in the plot, the standard deviations are mismatched.

I don't understand the reason.

Here is my demo data:

```r
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
BPData <- data.frame(
  Metabolite = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 5),
  Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 2),
  MEAN = c(7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7),
  SD = 1:10
)

> BPData
   Metabolite Group MEAN SD
1           X     A    7  1
2           X     B    6  2
3           X     C    7  3
4           X     D    3  4
5           X     E    7  5
6           Y     A    7  6
7           Y     B    7  7
8           Y     C    8  8
9           Y     D    7  9
10          Y     E    7 10
```

Below is my minimal example:

```r
BPData <- data.frame(
  Metabolite = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 5),
  Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 2),
  MEAN = c(7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7),
  SD = 1:10
)

BPData <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(BPData)
metaboliteFilter <- crosstalk::filter_select(id = "Metabolite", 
                                             label = "Select a metabolite", 
                                             sharedData = BPData, 
                                             group = ~ Metabolite, 
                                             multiple = F
)
BPPlot <- plotly::plot_ly(data = BPData,
                          x = ~ Group,
                          y = ~ MEAN,
                          color = ~ Group,
                          type = 'bar',
                          error_y = ~list(array = SD, color = '#808080')
) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "trace"))

filter <- crosstalk::bscols(
  metaboliteFilter, 
  BPPlot
)

crosstalk::bscols(filter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange bug of `plotly`.

> The error bars appear in the wrong order when grouping data by color.

So the solution is either to remove the `color` parameter or to re-order to data by the colored variable before making plot.

Here is my solution:

```r
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

BPData <- data.frame(
  Metabolite = rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 5),
  Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 2),
  MEAN = c(7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7),
  SD = 1:10
)

# must order data by the colored variable here
BPData <- BPData[order(BPData$Group),]

BPData <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(BPData)
metaboliteFilter <- crosstalk::filter_select(id = "Metabolite", 
                                             label = "Select a metabolite", 
                                             sharedData = BPData, 
                                             group = ~ Metabolite, 
                                             multiple = F
)
BPPlot <- plotly::plot_ly(data = BPData,
                          x = ~ Group,
                          y = ~ MEAN,
                          color = ~ Group,
                          error_y = ~list(array = SD, color = '#808080'),
                          type = 'bar'
                          ) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "trace"))

filter <- crosstalk::bscols(
  metaboliteFilter, 
  BPPlot
)

crosstalk::bscols(filter)
```